# 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x9a in position 3: ordinal not in range(128) while launching Moveit Setup Assiatant with roslaunch

Tags: moveit, roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I  installed Kinetic using http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu on a Ubuntu 16.04 machine and installed Moveit! using http://moveit.ros.org/install/.  When I execute roslaunch moveit_setup_assistant setup_assistant.launch, following instructions here, http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/setup_assistant/setup_assistant_tutorial.html, I get `[roslaunch][ERROR] 2017-01-02 11:25:28,199: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x9a in position 3: ordinal not in range(128).`

Uname -a information: Precision-5510 4.4.0-57-generic #78-Ubuntu SMP Fri Dec 9 23:50:32 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

env | grep ROS information:

```
ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/kinetic/share/ros
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/opt/ros/kinetic/share
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES=
ROS_DISTRO=kinetic
ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/kinetic/etc/ros
```

The complete log file is below.

Any help in resolving this would be greatly appreciated.  Please let me know if more information is needed.

Mike

```
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-01-02 11:25:27,837: Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-01-02 11:25:27,839: Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-01-02 11:25:27,840: roslaunch starting with args ['/opt/ros/kinetic/bin/roslaunch', 'moveit_setup_assistant', 'setup_assistant.launch']
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-01-02 11:25:27,840: roslaunch env is {'MANDATORY_PATH': '/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.mandatory.path', 'ROS_DISTRO': 'kinetic', 'ROS_LOG_FILENAME': '/home/mike/.ros/log/d5d1f0fe-d118-11e6-8c3f-34f39a87b69e/roslaunch-mike-Precision-5510-9950.log', 'XDG_GREETER_DATA_DIR': '/var/lib/lightdm-data/mike', 'GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID': 'this-is-deprecated', 'PKG_CONFIG_PATH': '/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/pkgconfig:/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig', 'UPSTART_EVENTS': 'started starting', 'LESSOPEN': '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s', 'XDG_SESSION_TYPE': 'x11', 'ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES': '', 'QT_IM_MODULE': 'ibus', 'LOGNAME': 'mike', 'USER': 'mike', 'PATH': '/opt/ros/kinetic/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin', 'XDG_VTNR': '7', 'GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL': '', 'CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH': '/opt/ros/kinetic', 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH': '/opt/ros/kinetic/lib:/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/home/mike/Spinnaker/spinnaker_1_0_0_295_amd64/lib/', 'LANG': 'en_US.UTF-8', 'TERM': 'xterm-256color', 'SHELL': '/bin/bash', 'XDG_SESSION_PATH': '/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0', 'XAUTHORITY': '/home/mike/.Xauthority', 'LANGUAGE': 'en_US', 'COMPIZ_CONFIG_PROFILE': 'ubuntu', 'SHLVL': '1', 'QT_LINUX_ACCESSIBILITY_ALWAYS_ON': '1', 'QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME': 'appmenu-qt5', 'CLUTTER_IM_MODULE': 'xim', 'DISPLAY': ':0', 'UPSTART_INSTANCE': '', 'QT_ACCESSIBILITY': '1', 'WINDOWID': '69206026', 'SESSIONTYPE': 'gnome-session', 'XMODIFIERS': '@im=ibus', 'ROS_ETC_DIR': '/opt/ros/kinetic/etc/ros', 'GPG_AGENT_INFO': '/home/mike/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1', 'HOME': '/home/mike', 'QT4_IM_MODULE': 'xim', 'GTK2_MODULES': 'overlay-scrollbar', 'XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP': 'ubuntu', 'XDG_RUNTIME_DIR': '/run/user/1001', 'INSTANCE': 'Unity', 'PYTHONPATH': '/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', 'SSH_AUTH_SOCK': '/run/user/1001/keyring/ssh', 'VTE_VERSION': '4205', 'ROS_ROOT': '/opt/ros/kinetic/share/ros', 'GDMSESSION': 'ubuntu', 'IM_CONFIG_PHASE': '1', 'UPSTART_JOB': 'unity-settings-daemon', 'LESSCLOSE': '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s', 'GNOME_KEYRING_PID': '', 'XDG_SEAT_PATH': '/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0', 'ROS_PACKAGE_PATH': '/opt/ros/kinetic/share', 'XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP': 'Unity', 'XDG_SESSION_ID': 'c8', 'DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS': 'unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-j8R8N43uH9', '_': '/opt/ros/kinetic/bin/roslaunch', 'DEFAULTS_PATH': '/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.default.path', 'GTK_IM_MODULE': 'ibus', 'DESKTOP_SESSION': 'ubuntu', 'UPSTART_SESSION': 'unix:abstract=/com/ubuntu/upstart-session/1001/2096', 'XDG_CONFIG_DIRS': '/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/usr/share/upstart/xdg:/etc/xdg', 'GTK_MODULES': 'gail:atk-bridge:unity-gtk-module', 'GDM_LANG': 'en_US', 'XDG_DATA_DIRS': '/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop', 'PWD': '/home/mike', 'JOB': 'gnome-session', 'ROS_MASTER_URI': 'http://localhost:11311', 'DESKTOP_MODE': '1', 'LS_COLORS': 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:', 'XDG_SEAT': 'seat0'}
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-01-02 11:25:27,840: starting in server mode
[roslaunch.parent][INFO] 2017-01-02 11:25:27,840: starting roslaunch parent run
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-01-02 11:25:27,840: loading roscore config file /opt/ros/kinetic/etc/ros/roscore.xml
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-01-02 11:25:27,907: Added core node of type [rosout/rosout] in namespace [/]
[roslaunch.config][INFO] 2017-01-02 11:25:27,908: loading config file /opt/ros/kinetic/share/moveit_setup_assistant/launch/setup_assistant.launch
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-01-02 11:25:27,908: Added node of type [moveit_setup_assistant/moveit_setup_assistant] in namespace [/]
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-01-02 11:25:27,908: ... selected machine [] for node of type [moveit_setup_assistant/moveit_setup_assistant]
[roslaunch.pmon][INFO] 2017-01-02 11:25:27,909: start_process_monitor: creating ProcessMonitor
[roslaunch.pmon][INFO] 2017-01-02 11:25:27,909: created process monitor <ProcessMonitor(ProcessMonitor-1, initial daemon)>
[roslaunch.pmon][INFO] 2017-01-02 11:25:27,909: start_process_monitor: ProcessMonitor started
[roslaunch.parent][INFO] 2017-01-02 11:25:27,909: starting parent XML-RPC server
[roslaunch.server][INFO] 2017-01-02 11:25:27,909: starting roslaunch XML-RPC server
[roslaunch.server][INFO] 2017-01-02 11:25:27,909: waiting for roslaunch XML-RPC server to initialize
[xmlrpc][INFO] 2017-01-02 11:25:27,909: XML-RPC server binding to 0.0.0.0:0
[xmlrpc][INFO] 2017-01-02 11:25:27,910: Started XML-RPC server [http://mike-Precision-5510:40754/]
[xmlrpc][INFO] 2017-01-02 11:25:27,910: xml rpc node: starting XML-RPC server
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-01-02 11:25:27,921: started roslaunch server http://mike-Precision-5510:40754/
[roslaunch.parent][INFO] 2017-01-02 11:25:27,921: ... parent XML-RPC server started
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-01-02 11:25:27,921: master.is_running[http://localhost:11311]
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-01-02 11:25:27,921: auto-starting new master
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-01-02 11:25:27,922: create_master_process: rosmaster, /opt/ros/kinetic/share/ros, 11311, 3, None
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-01-02 11:25:27,922: process[master]: launching with args [['rosmaster', '--core', '-p', '11311', '-w', '3']]
[roslaunch.pmon][INFO] 2017-01-02 11:25:27,922: ProcessMonitor.register[master]
[roslaunch.pmon][INFO] 2017-01-02 11:25:27,922: ProcessMonitor.register[master] complete
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-01-02 11:25:27,922: process[master]: starting os process
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-01-02 11:25:27,922: process[master]: start w/ args [['rosmaster', '--core', '-p', '11311', '-w', '3', '__log:=/home/mike/.ros/log/d5d1f0fe-d118-11e6-8c3f-34f39a87b69e/master.log']]
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-01-02 11:25:27,922: process[master]: cwd will be [/home/mike/.ros]
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-01-02 11:25:27,924: process[master]: started with pid [9961]
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-01-02 11:25:27,924: master.is_running[http://localhost:11311]
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-01-02 11:25:28,025: master.is_running[http://localhost:11311]
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-01-02 11:25:28,126: master.is_running[http://localhost:11311]
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-01-02 11:25:28,130: master.is_running[http://localhost:11311]
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-01-02 11:25:28,133: ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-01-02 11:25:28,135: setting /run_id to d5d1f0fe-d118-11e6-8c3f-34f39a87b69e
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-01-02 11:25:28,139: setting /roslaunch/uris/host_mike_precision_5510__40754' to http://mike-Precision-5510:40754/
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-01-02 11:25:28,144: ... preparing to launch node of type [rosout/rosout]
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-01-02 11:25:28,144: create_node_process: package[rosout] type[rosout] machine[Machine(name[] env_loader[None] address[localhost] ssh_port[22] user[None] assignable[True] timeout[10.0])] master_uri[http://localhost:11311]
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-01-02 11:25:28,145: process[rosout-1]: env[{'QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME': 'appmenu-qt5', 'ROS_DISTRO': 'kinetic', 'XDG_GREETER_DATA_DIR': '/var/lib/lightdm-data/mike', 'GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID': 'this-is-deprecated', 'UPSTART_EVENTS': 'started starting', 'LESSOPEN': '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s', 'XDG_SESSION_ID': 'c8', 'XDG_SESSION_TYPE': 'x11', 'ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES': '', 'QT_IM_MODULE': 'ibus', 'LOGNAME': 'mike', 'USER': 'mike', 'PATH': '/opt/ros/kinetic/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin', 'XDG_VTNR': '7', 'GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL': '', 'ROS_PACKAGE_PATH': '/opt/ros/kinetic/share', 'CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH': '/opt/ros/kinetic', 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH': '/opt/ros/kinetic/lib:/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/home/mike/Spinnaker/spinnaker_1_0_0_295_amd64/lib/', 'LANG': 'en_US.UTF-8', 'TERM': 'xterm-256color', 'SHELL': '/bin/bash', 'XDG_SESSION_PATH': '/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0', 'XAUTHORITY': '/home/mike/.Xauthority', 'LANGUAGE': 'en_US', 'SHLVL': '1', 'QT_LINUX_ACCESSIBILITY_ALWAYS_ON': '1', 'MANDATORY_PATH': '/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.mandatory.path', 'CLUTTER_IM_MODULE': 'xim', 'ROS_LOG_FILENAME': '/home/mike/.ros/log/d5d1f0fe-d118-11e6-8c3f-34f39a87b69e/roslaunch-mike-Precision-5510-9950.log', 'UPSTART_INSTANCE': '', 'COMPIZ_CONFIG_PROFILE': 'ubuntu', 'WINDOWID': '69206026', 'SESSIONTYPE': 'gnome-session', 'XMODIFIERS': '@im=ibus', 'ROS_MASTER_URI': 'http://localhost:11311', 'GPG_AGENT_INFO': '/home/mike/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1', 'HOME': '/home/mike', 'QT4_IM_MODULE': 'xim', 'GTK2_MODULES': 'overlay-scrollbar', 'XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP': 'ubuntu', 'XDG_RUNTIME_DIR': '/run/user/1001', 'PYTHONPATH': '/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', 'SSH_AUTH_SOCK': '/run/user/1001/keyring/ssh', 'VTE_VERSION': '4205', 'ROS_ROOT': '/opt/ros/kinetic/share/ros', 'GDMSESSION': 'ubuntu', 'IM_CONFIG_PHASE': '1', 'UPSTART_JOB': 'unity-settings-daemon', 'QT_ACCESSIBILITY': '1', 'PKG_CONFIG_PATH': '/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/pkgconfig:/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig', 'LESSCLOSE': '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s', 'XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP': 'Unity', 'XDG_SEAT_PATH': '/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0', 'DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS': 'unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-j8R8N43uH9', '_': '/opt/ros/kinetic/bin/roslaunch', 'DEFAULTS_PATH': '/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.default.path', 'GTK_IM_MODULE': 'ibus', 'DESKTOP_SESSION': 'ubuntu', 'UPSTART_SESSION': 'unix:abstract=/com/ubuntu/upstart-session/1001/2096', 'DISPLAY': ':0', 'GNOME_KEYRING_PID': '', 'LS_COLORS': 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:', 'GDM_LANG': 'en_US', 'GTK_MODULES': 'gail:atk-bridge:unity-gtk-module', 'INSTANCE': 'Unity', 'PWD': '/home/mike', 'JOB': 'gnome-session', 'ROS_ETC_DIR': '/opt/ros/kinetic/etc/ros', 'DESKTOP_MODE': '1', 'XDG_CONFIG_DIRS': '/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/usr/share/upstart/xdg:/etc/xdg', 'XDG_DATA_DIRS': '/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop', 'XDG_SEAT': 'seat0'}]
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-01-02 11:25:28,192: process[rosout-1]: args[[u'/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/rosout/rosout', u'__name:=rosout']]
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-01-02 11:25:28,192: ... created process [rosout-1]
[roslaunch.pmon][INFO] 2017-01-02 11:25:28,193: ProcessMonitor.register[rosout-1]
[roslaunch.pmon][INFO] 2017-01-02 11:25:28,193: ProcessMonitor.register[rosout-1] complete
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-01-02 11:25:28,193: ... registered process [rosout-1]
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-01-02 11:25:28,193: process[rosout-1]: starting os process
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-01-02 11:25:28,193: process[rosout-1]: start w/ args [[u'/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/rosout/rosout', u'__name:=rosout', u'__log:=/home/mike/.ros/log/d5d1f0fe-d118-11e6-8c3f-34f39a87b69e/rosout-1.log']]
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-01-02 11:25:28,193: process[rosout-1]: cwd will be [/home/mike/.ros]
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-01-02 11:25:28,195: process[rosout-1]: started with pid [9974]
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-01-02 11:25:28,195: ... successfully launched [rosout-1]
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-01-02 11:25:28,196: load_parameters starting ...
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-01-02 11:25:28,198: ... load_parameters complete
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-01-02 11:25:28,198: launch_nodes: launching local nodes ...
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-01-02 11:25:28,198: ... preparing to launch node of type [moveit_setup_assistant/moveit_setup_assistant]
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-01-02 11:25:28,198: create_node_process: package[moveit_setup_assistant] type[moveit_setup_assistant] machine[Machine(name[] env_loader[None] address[localhost] ssh_port[22] user[None] assignable[True] timeout[10.0])] master_uri[http://localhost:11311]
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-01-02 11:25:28,199: process[moveit_setup_assistant-2]: env[{'QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME': 'appmenu-qt5', 'ROS_DISTRO': 'kinetic', 'XDG_GREETER_DATA_DIR': '/var/lib/lightdm-data/mike', 'GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID': 'this-is-deprecated', 'UPSTART_EVENTS': 'started starting', 'LESSOPEN': '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s', 'XDG_SESSION_ID': 'c8', 'XDG_SESSION_TYPE': 'x11', 'ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES': '', 'QT_IM_MODULE': 'ibus', 'LOGNAME': 'mike', 'USER': 'mike', 'PATH': '/opt/ros/kinetic/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin', 'XDG_VTNR': '7', 'GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL': '', 'ROS_PACKAGE_PATH': '/opt/ros/kinetic/share', 'CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH': '/opt/ros/kinetic', 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH': '/opt/ros/kinetic/lib:/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/home/mike/Spinnaker/spinnaker_1_0_0_295_amd64/lib/', 'LANG': 'en_US.UTF-8', 'TERM': 'xterm-256color', 'SHELL': '/bin/bash', 'XDG_SESSION_PATH': '/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0', 'XAUTHORITY': '/home/mike/.Xauthority', 'LANGUAGE': 'en_US', 'SHLVL': '1', 'QT_LINUX_ACCESSIBILITY_ALWAYS_ON': '1', 'MANDATORY_PATH': '/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.mandatory.path', 'CLUTTER_IM_MODULE': 'xim', 'ROS_LOG_FILENAME': '/home/mike/.ros/log/d5d1f0fe-d118-11e6-8c3f-34f39a87b69e/roslaunch-mike-Precision-5510-9950.log', 'UPSTART_INSTANCE': '', 'COMPIZ_CONFIG_PROFILE': 'ubuntu', 'WINDOWID': '69206026', 'SESSIONTYPE': 'gnome-session', 'XMODIFIERS': '@im=ibus', 'ROS_MASTER_URI': 'http://localhost:11311', 'GPG_AGENT_INFO': '/home/mike/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1', 'HOME': '/home/mike', 'QT4_IM_MODULE': 'xim', 'GTK2_MODULES': 'overlay-scrollbar', 'XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP': 'ubuntu', 'XDG_RUNTIME_DIR': '/run/user/1001', 'PYTHONPATH': '/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', 'SSH_AUTH_SOCK': '/run/user/1001/keyring/ssh', 'VTE_VERSION': '4205', 'ROS_ROOT': '/opt/ros/kinetic/share/ros', 'GDMSESSION': 'ubuntu', 'IM_CONFIG_PHASE': '1', 'UPSTART_JOB': 'unity-settings-daemon', 'QT_ACCESSIBILITY': '1', 'PKG_CONFIG_PATH': '/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/pkgconfig:/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig', 'LESSCLOSE': '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s', 'XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP': 'Unity', 'XDG_SEAT_PATH': '/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0', 'DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS': 'unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-j8R8N43uH9', '_': '/opt/ros/kinetic/bin/roslaunch', 'DEFAULTS_PATH': '/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.default.path', 'GTK_IM_MODULE': 'ibus', 'DESKTOP_SESSION': 'ubuntu', 'UPSTART_SESSION': 'unix:abstract=/com/ubuntu/upstart-session/1001/2096', 'DISPLAY': ':0', 'GNOME_KEYRING_PID': '', 'LS_COLORS': 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:', 'GDM_LANG': 'en_US', 'GTK_MODULES': 'gail:atk-bridge:unity-gtk-module', 'INSTANCE': 'Unity', 'PWD': '/home/mike', 'JOB': 'gnome-session', 'ROS_ETC_DIR': '/opt/ros/kinetic/etc/ros', 'DESKTOP_MODE': '1', 'XDG_CONFIG_DIRS': '/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/usr/share/upstart/xdg:/etc/xdg', 'XDG_DATA_DIRS': '/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop', 'XDG_SEAT': 'seat0'}]
[roslaunch][ERROR] 2017-01-02 11:25:28,199: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x9a in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)
[roslaunch][ERROR] 2017-01-02 11:25:28,199: The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
[roslaunch][ERROR] 2017-01-02 11:25:28,200: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/__init__.py", line 307, in main
    p.start()
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 279, in start
    self.runner.launch()
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/launch.py", line 655, in launch
    succeeded, failed = self._launch_nodes()
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/launch.py", line 367, in _launch_nodes
    proc, success = self.launch_node(node)
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/launch.py", line 534, in launch_node
    process = create_node_process(self.run_id, node, master.uri)
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/nodeprocess.py", line 139, in create_node_process
    args = create_local_process_args(node, machine)
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/node_args.py", line 251, in create_local_process_args
    matches = roslib.packages.find_node(node.package, node.type, rospack=rospack)
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/packages.py", line 400, in find_node
    return find_resource(pkg, node_type, filter_fn=_executable_filter, rospack=rospack)
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/packages.py", line 511, in find_resource
    matches.extend(_find_resource(search_path, resource_name, filter_fn=filter_fn))
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/packages.py", line 446, in _find_resource
    for p, dirs, files in os.walk(d):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 286, in walk
    if isdir(join(top, name)):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 73, in join
    path += '/' + b
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x9a in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)

[roslaunch.pmon][INFO] 2017-01-02 11:25:28,200: ProcessMonitor.shutdown <ProcessMonitor(ProcessMonitor-1, started daemon 140261644834560)>
[roslaunch.pmon][INFO] 2017-01-02 11:25:28,210: ProcessMonitor._post_run <ProcessMonitor(ProcessMonitor-1, started daemon 140261644834560)>
[roslaunch.pmon][INFO] 2017-01-02 11:25:28,210: ProcessMonitor._post_run <ProcessMonitor(ProcessMonitor-1, started daemon 140261644834560)>: remaining procs are [<roslaunch.nodeprocess.LocalProcess object at 0x7f9135a4e950>, <roslaunch.nodeprocess.LocalProcess object at 0x7f9135a4ee90>]
[roslaunch.pmon][INFO] 2017-01-02 11:25:28,211: ProcessMonitor exit: killing rosout-1
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-01-02 11:25:28,211: [rosout-1] killing on exit
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-01-02 11:25:28,211: process[rosout-1]: killing os process with pid[9974] pgid[9974]
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-01-02 11:25:28,211: [rosout-1] sending SIGINT to pgid [9974]
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-01-02 11:25:28,211: [rosout-1] sent SIGINT to pgid [9974]
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-01-02 11:25:28,512: process[rosout-1]: SIGINT killed with return value 0
[roslaunch.pmon][INFO] 2017-01-02 11:25:28,512: ProcessMonitor exit: killing master
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-01-02 11:25:28,513: [master] killing on exit
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-01-02 11:25:28,513: process[master]: killing os process with pid[9961] pgid[9961]
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-01-02 11:25:28,513: [master] sending SIGINT to pgid [9961]
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-01-02 11:25:28,513: [master] sent SIGINT to pgid [9961]
[roslaunch][INFO] 2017-01-02 11:25:28,714: process[master]: SIGINT killed with return value 0
[roslaunch.pmon][INFO] 2017-01-02 11:25:28,715: ProcessMonitor exit: cleaning up data structures and signals
[roslaunch.pmon][INFO] 2017-01-02 11:25:28,715: ProcessMonitor exit: pmon has shutdown
[rospy.core][INFO] 2017-01-02 11:25:28,716: signal_shutdown [atexit]
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/251164/%27ascii%27-codec-can%27t-decode-byte-0x9a-in-position-3:-ordinal-not-in-range(128)-while-launching-moveit-setup-assiatant-with-roslaunch./) by [MikeArmstrong](https://answers.ros.org/users/28937/mikearmstrong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-01-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems like there's a non-ascii character (probably `š`) in one of the file names of one of the files on your system, and the python library for dealing with paths and filenames (`os.path.isdir`) doesn't like that.

I realize that's not very specific, but without modifying roslaunch to add additional debug information, there's not much more I can say.

You can search for files with that character in the file name in /opt/ros with `find /opt/ros -name '*š*'`. If that doesn't find anything, you can try searching the whole file system: `find / -name '*š*'` (give this an hour or two to run if you have a large file system, a slow hard drive, or both)

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-01-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks ahendrix.  As it turns out there was a zero length file named ?p?@@ in the //opt/ros/kinetic/lib/moveit_setup_assistant directory.  I don't know how it got there as this is a clean installation of Kinetic.  But all is well and Setup Assistant runs.

Thanks again,

Mike

---

Originally posted by [MikeArmstrong](https://answers.ros.org/users/28937/mikearmstrong/) with karma: 11 on 2017-01-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) on 2017-01-04**:
I just installed that debian on my system and could not find a similar file. If you are able to track down a fix please contribute to the Github repo, thanks!